# Is the carrying of knives in the street regulated in Malaysia?

Tags: legal, security, malaysia, cold-weapons

Some countries do not allow the carrying of a knife in the street.

Is there such a regulation in Malaysia?

Comment: thanks for this wonderful replies. if anyone has any experience please post it here. I believe some regulation not applied in reality.

Comment: @pnuts I believe the edit changes the question. I think small Swiss army knife where the blade is smaller than 3 inches is OK to carry around.

Comment: I post this Q and I was asking about the *legality* of doing this deed not about what the people think about it.

Answer (score 10):

Yes there is.

According to [this](http://www.lawyerment.com/answers/questions/1649/carrying-knife-legal-or-illegal):

> Carrying a knife is illegal in Malaysia. You will be arrested and charged under the Corrosive, Explosive and Dangerous Weapons Act 1958 which carries a jail term of up to two years and whipping, upon conviction. Some people do carry short knife for defense purposes and never get caught. Those caught and charged are likely arrested by police upon receiving call from the public or security guard (樣衰) accused on suspicion. Some are even arrested for carrying knife in front of their own house - perhaps wielding their knife or mannerism carrying a knife.

Comment: Hmm... That answer doesn't really seem to agree with [the actual law](http://www.commonlii.org/my/legis/consol_act/caesaowa19581988652/). The law says it's only illegal if it's not carried "with lawful authority or for a lawful purpose." Also, the law applies to "any instrument which if used as a weapon of offence is likely to cause hurt." A car fits that definition just as well as a knife does. So does a wrench, a metal pipe, or a rope. The key to whether it's illegal to "carry or have in [your] possession in public" seems to be the "other than for a lawful purpose" part.

Answer (score -9):

I think it would be illegal to carry knife in public everywhere. So the answer is

**NO**, you can't carry it public.

Comment: Can you provide any source for your answer?

Comment: "Everywhere" is a big place

Comment: It is not illegal to carry a knife in public everywhere. For example, in the UK, it's legal to carry a knife such as a Swiss Army knife with a small (I forget the actual length) non-locking blade.

Comment: The U.S. is another example of a place where carrying a pocket knife such as a Swiss Army knife in public is, not only legal, but perfectly normal practice. I carry one daily. It's extremely convenient to have.

Comment: Counterexample: the state of Montana permits you to carry a fixed-blade knife of any length, as long as you carry it openly.  Swords are fine, sword-canes are not.